# Verify that the Divergence Theorem is true for $ \ F = \langle 2x, −3y, z^2\rangle \ $

Tags: calculus

Verify that the Divergence Theorem is true for  $ \ F = \langle 2x, −3y, z^2\rangle \ $ and the region $ \  E \ $ enclosed by the cylinder $ \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \ $ and the planes $ \  z = 0 \ $ and  $ \ z = x + 2 \ $ with outward orientation.

**Answer:**

$ \ F = \langle 2x, −3y, z^2\rangle \\ \Rightarrow div (F)=2z-1 $

By divergence theorem ,

$ \iint_S F \cdot n dS=\iiint_E div (F) dV \ $

Now,

$ \iiint_E div (F) dV \\ =\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{0}^{x+2} (2z-1) dzdy dx \\ = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} [z^2-z]_{0}^{x+2} dydx \\ = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (x^2+3x+2) dydx \\ = \large \frac{9 \pi}{4}$

**Now to verify divergence theorem** , we have to evaluate $ \ \iint_S F \cdot n dS \ $

**Help me to evaluate this.**

Comment: What don't you understand? You need to compute the flux of your field through the surface. Your surface can be decomposed into the bottom disk, the top (slanted elliptical region), and the sides of the cylinder. Compute the flux through each of these three pieces, and then sum the results.

Comment: how to find the unit outward normal $ n \ $ ?

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the flux integral directly you will need to break the surface $S$ into three pieces, say, Side, Top, and Bottom to then calculate
\begin{align}
\iint_S F\cdot n\, dS=\iint_{Bottom} F\cdot n\, dS+\iint_{Top} F\cdot n \, dS+\iint_{Side} F\cdot n\, dS.
\end{align}
Then the corresponding unit outward vectors are $\langle 0,0,-1\rangle$ for the bottom surface, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle -1,0,1\rangle$ for the top surface, and $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\langle x,y,0\rangle$ for the side surface.

The flux through the bottom surface is zero. You just need to calculate the remaining flux integrals.